# How do I edit my own question?

Tags: support, editing

I posed a question with the [trello](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trello) tag. Rather soon I realized my question was based on a premature conclusion of mine but not before my question was answered. I needed to rephrase the question, which I did, and got a response along the lines of "since you're a rather unqualified question-asker we need to put your edit on hold for approval" or so.

So, what gives?

This was four days ago, and I really need to find an answer to my edited question.

Answer (score 5):

That restriction should only happen if you're under 2000 rep (or 100 rep on posts marked community wiki) and editing someone else's post.

That could also happen if you accidentally logged out and tried to edit your own post.

In your case, it was because you were not logged in under the same account (maybe from another browser) and [the suggested edit was seen as too drastic](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/review-beta/suggested-edits/2602) to the original.

With no way to verify that the anonymous suggestion was yours it would change too much of the voice of what's there. Keep in mind that if you need to update your post, that you check that you're logged in.